# Is it possible to create an https request in Node.js without using Openssl?

Tags: node.js, ssl

In the course of a project, I've been running into a wall sending https requests to (usually older) sites. While the sites navigate in the browser just fine, they throw 502 errors when the request is made from Node. More specifically, they claim SSL Bad handshake. But cURL requests go through just fine.

I think I've narrowed down the issue to the use of OpenSSL in Node. For instance, an analysis of the site by SSL Labs tells me that, in a handshake simulation:

> OpenSSL 0.9.8y    RSA 2048 (SHA256)   TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>
> OpenSSL 1.0.1l  R Server closed connection
>
> OpenSSL 1.0.2e  R Server closed connection

So connections with later versions of OpenSSL tend to get killed before the request goes through.

Now, I could, I think, cook it up so that the script just makes cURL requests, but I would rather have a solution that doesn't have any extra dependencies. Is there a possible solution here?

EDIT: If possible, I would be interested in hypotheses as to why later versions of OpenSSL fail while all other sorts of handshake simulations succeed.

I've tried to play around with the cipher suite, but so far it hasn't helped. Here is my code (node version in 4.6.2, in case it matters):

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  hostname: 'thewebsite.net',
  port: 443,
  agent: false,
  servername: 'thewebsite.net',
  path: '/',
  ciphers: 'ALL',
  method: 'GET'
};

https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

I've played around with secureProtocol, agent, and serverName options, but thus far nothing seems to work. Depending on which options are used, either I receive a 502 error that cites an SSL handshake problem, or:

```
Caught exception: Error: socket hang up
at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1054:19)
at TLSSocket.g (events.js:260:16)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:923:12)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:458:9)
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:413:17)
```

Comment: Are any of the sites public?

Comment: Yes. The sites are public, though part of the project is to automate logins to protected routes. But regardless of whether the route is protected or not, the same errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually specify what ciphers to use for a request by setting the `ciphers` option. The format of the `ciphers` list follows [the OpenSSL cipher list format](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER-LIST-FORMAT).

FWIW the [default cipher list](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener) used by node currently (as of node v7.2.0) is (minus the line breaks):

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:
HIGH:
!aNULL:
!eNULL:
!EXPORT:
!DES:
!RC4:
!MD5:
!PSK:
!SRP:
!CAMELLIA
```

Comment: I've tried playing with the ciphers, but so far it hasn't made a difference, as I've noted in the edit above.